# How can I have exhaustive conditions nested in the widget tree?

Tags: flutter

For enums and Sealed Class subtypes for example.

I know you can use a function that contains a switch statement but it's generally considered bad practice to have functions in the widget tree isn't it?
I'd worry it would mess up widget rebuilding on state changes or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart 3 introduced Switch Expressions which can be used for this.

They are different to Switch Statements which couldn't be used because they don't return a value directly, whereas the expressions do.

```
    switch (equipment) {
      Computer() => const Text('Computer'),
      Ladder() => const Text('Ladder'),
      Smartphone() => const Text('Smartphone'),
      Microscope() => const Text('Microscope'),
    }
```